# How can I programatically open Pending Changes - Conflict Window?

Tags: api, sdk, tfs

I need to open Conflict Tab in Pending Changes Window:

I already have:

```
  Object customIn = null;
  Object customOut = null;
  //Show TfsPendingChanges
  m_applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("View.TfsPendingChanges", "");
  //Refresh
  m_applicationObject.Commands.Raise("{FFE1131C-8EA1-4D05-9728-34AD4611BDA9}", 4808, ref customIn, ref customOut);
  customOut = null;

  //Get Conflicts
  m_applicationObject.Commands.Raise("{FFE1131C-8EA1-4D05-9728-34AD4611BDA9}", 4832, ref customIn, ref customOut);
```

But I did not find a way to open Conflict TAB ! Even Get Conflicts button (4832) does not trigger that TAB !

Anyone could help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void refreshPendingChanges()
{
  Object customIn = null;
  Object customOut = null;

  //Show TfsPendingChanges
  m_applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("View.TfsPendingChanges", "");

  //Refresh
  m_applicationObject.Commands.Raise("{FFE1131C-8EA1-4D05-9728-34AD4611BDA9}", 4808, ref customIn, ref customOut);

  //Activate Source Explorer
  m_applicationObject.DTE.Windows.Item("{99B8FA2F-AB90-4F57-9C32-949F146F1914}").Activate(); //I get this GUID recording a Macro.
  //Show Conflicts
  m_applicationObject.DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.TfsResumeConflictResolution"); 
}
```

Thanks to Chad Boles ! that said me about TfsResumeConflictResolution DTE Command.